# Android webview loadurl cause native crash after WebViewTransport.sendToTarget

Tags: android, android-webview

webview settings:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
```

webChromeClient settings:

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {

            WebView childWebView = new WebView(view.getContext());

            childWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

            parentView.addView(childWebView);
            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(childWebView);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
            super.onCloseWindow(window);
            parentView.removeView(window);
        }
});
```

webViewclient settings:

```
class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
        return true;
    }

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);

        return true;
    }
}
```

problem:

when click `a` tag with `target="_blank"` (eg, `<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">`), app native crash. **signal 5 (SIGTRAP)**

but `window.open(url)` it runs without any problem.

i have searched the google issuetracker but couldn't find a solution.

it's a bug??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a old bug.

see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241151499

from google issue tracker.